# Saving files to a specific directory in Java?

Tags: java

This is probably a silly question, but I'm pretty new to Java and I can't figure it out.
 Basically, I'm trying to download some files from a website and I want to save them to a particular folder (rather than the default of the same folder that my Java file is located in). How can I do this?

I've been using `FileReader`, `BufferedReader`, `BufferedInputStream`, and `FileOutputStream classes`.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know at compile time the name of the directory?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java is pretty friendly with IO. Try something like this:

```
File file = new File("/some/absolute/path/myfile.ext");
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
// Write your data
out.close();
```

Notes:

- Your program needs permission to write to the directory.
- If the first character of your path string is not `/`, it will be relative to your "current" directory
- If you're writing text, you might find a `BufferedWriter` easier: `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));`. It has `newLine()` and `write(String)` methods

Comment: As always, don't forget to handle IOException. And it's often a good idea to put the close() in a `finally` block.

Comment: One more note -- you can separate the directory from the file name by using the alternate constructor for File... it takes the directory as a File... See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: @Bohemian how to store pdf file to a specific location?

Comment: @RahulKulhari Assuming you have a `byte[] myByteArray` containing a pdf, use the code above and where it says "write your data" put `out.write(myByteArray);`

Answer (score 3):

When you insantiate your `FileOutputStream` you can pass an absolute path to the constructor. Like this:

```
FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.txt");
```